# Запрос для поиска элементов

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Надо при нажатых кнопках отображать определенные элементы из базы. Вот пример кода:

```
using (AccidentContext db = new AccidentContext())
        {
            if (_buttonFrunzEnabled)
            {
                var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => p.District == "ФРУНЗ");
            }

            if (_buttonNordEnabled)
            {
                var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => p.District == "СЕВЕР");
            }

            if (_buttonSouthEnabled)
            {
                var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => p.District == "ЮГ");
            }

            if (_buttonLENEnabled)
            {
                var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => p.District == "ЛЕН");
            }
        }
```

А как нормально отрабатывать запрос при нажатых нескольких кнопках?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    using (AccidentContext db = new AccidentContext())
    {
        var districts = new[]{ "ФРУНЗ", "СЕВЕР" };
        var accidents = db.Accidents.Where(p => districts.Contains(p.District));
        // Можно использовать и для одного элемента и для массива
    }
```